# How to create KeyCollection from array in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have hash like this:

```
   $NATO = @{
        "A" = "Alpha";
        "B" = "Bravo";
        "C" = "Charlie";
        # ...
        "Y" = "Yankee";
        "Z" = "Zulu";
    }
```

I could get all values of hash using `$NATO.keys` key collection:

```
    $NATO[$NATO.keys] # gives me all values
```

But if I want to pass subset of keys, to get subset of values, I can't do that:

```
    $NATO["BUNYK".ToCharArray()] # gives me nothing, but I want 
    # Bravo, Uniform, November, Yankee, Kilo
```

Do you know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash table stores the keys as objects, not necessarily simple strings. The keys in your example are strings, but you're trying to access them as [char] objects. The easiest way to handle your example is to cast the [char[]] array to a [string[]] array:

```
$NATO[([string[]] "BUNYK".ToCharArray())]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also pipe the string array into a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
 [string[]]'BUNYK'.ToCharArray() | % { $NATO[$_] }
```